# Is it possible to downgrade from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a wonderful solution in [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) with a Web project using WebAPI and a supporting Web Service project for data using [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) (EF) Code First. I was just told I need to see about using Visual Studio 2010.

Is there something I can do to work on this project in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Henrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13289670/67392) answers: you do not upgrade/downgrade VS installs, rather you install versions side by side.

You note two technologies that might be problematic:

1. EF Code First: this is supported from 4.1 (or was it 4.2?) which is supported against .NET 4.0 and VS2010. Providing your not using `enum` or geo/spatial data types (which require .NET 4.5) this should work, but you'll need to ensure you update to the EF5 NuGet package for .NET 4.
2. WebAPI: This is new in MVC4, which comes with VS2012, but is a separate install for .NET 4/VS2010.

Finally. While some project types with round trip between VS2012 and VS2010 *SP1* (you need the service pack) it is not true for all project types. Details are on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh266747.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can install Visual Studio 2010 separately and open the project and see. There is no danger in having version 2005, 2008, 2010 or 2012 of Visual Studio installed.

Comment: I have 2010 on this machine.  Each project says ProjectName (incompatible).

Comment: Hmm yeah, take a backup of the try to create a new project and throw them into the project and include all the files, might just be the csproj file that have changed. However if its a bigger project it might not be a grade idea, since u proberbly need to add a whole bunch of refs.